# SQL - Finding unique values on two tables

Tags: sql, join, group-by, distinct

I have two tables where I want to find

a. distinct usernames, non-distinct document#, and non-distinct location names

b. distinct usernames, non-distinct document#, and distinct location names

These are two separate sql queries.

Here is what those tables would look like:

User Table

```
|---------------------------------------|------------|
| UserId       | UserName     |Document#| LocationId |
|---------------------------------------|------------|
|  1           |  bob2#       | DL      |   1        |
|---------------------------------------|------------|
|  2           |  mary3#      | Passport|   2        |
|---------------------------------------|------------|
|  3           |  bob2#       | SIN#    |   4        |
|---------------------------------------|------------|
|  4           |  sam5#       | DL      |   3        |
|---------------------------------------|------------|
|  5           |  bob2#       | SIN#    |   1        |
|---------------------------------------|------------|
```

Location Table

```
|---------------------------------------|
| LocationId   | UserId   |LocName      |
|---------------------------------------|
|  1           |   1      | Denvor      |
|---------------------------------------|
|  2           |   2      |  NY         |
|---------------------------------------|
|  3           |   3      | San Fran    |
|---------------------------------------|
|  4           |   4      | Chicago     |
|---------------------------------------|
```

This is what I've tried, for part a)

```
select User.UserName, User.Document#, Location.LocName 
from User Inner Join
     Location
     On User.UserId = Location.LocationId
Group by User.UserName
```

This is for part b)

```
select User.UserName, User.Document#, Location.LocName 
from User Inner Join
     Location
     On User.UserId = Location.LocationId
Group by User.UserName, Location.LocName
```

Can someone shed some light as to how to approach this?

Comment: new problem arises, consider 1st query : there are three `bob2#` with two distinct Location ID, and Document#, what's the logic about which of them you'll prefer ..?

Comment: Please add the results that you want.  The question is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need aggregation with your group by

Example you can group by User.UserName and get number of Documents (Count), and Count of Location.LocName

```
select User.UserName, Count(User.Document#), Count(Distinct Location.LocName) 
from User
Inner Join Location On User.UserId = Location.LocationId
Group by User.UserName
```

**Edit :**

I think you are doing the join wrong as you joining User ID to Location ID

It should be

```
select User.UserName, Count(User.Document#), Count(Distinct Location.LocName) 
from User
Inner Join Location On User.LocationId = Location.LocationId
Group by User.UserName
```

Comment: can I use max(User.Document#) and max(Distinct Location.LocName) ?

Comment: You can use Max, which will give you the max number, but you cannot use Max(Distinct

Comment: In my example, if were to use max, will this work even if I don't have a number? Example: max(Location.LocName)

Comment: Yes, it will give you the latest Location.LocName ordered from a-z